# C# program doesn't update SQL database from DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, sql-update

i'm trying to make some changes to a loaded dataGridView and then store these changes back to my database . The problem is that no update is commited back to the database .

Fill code for the datagridView

```
 private void fillAitimata(DataGridView dg)
    {
        try
        {
            aitimataShowCommand = login.connection.CreateCommand();

            aitimataShowCommand.CommandText = "select * from aitimata";
            aitimataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(aitimataShowCommand);
            aitimataDs = new DataSet();

            aitimataAdapter.Fill(aitimataDs, "Aitimata");
            dg.DataSource = aitimataDs.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        catch (MySqlException exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Update Code

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        MySqlCommandBuilder updateCommand = new MySqlCommandBuilder(aitimataAdapter);
        aitimataDs.AcceptChanges();
        aitimataAdapter.Update(aitimataDs, "Aitimata");
        dataGridView4.Refresh();
    }
```

Is my approach correct ? if so whats wrong with my code? Please let me know if more code is required for solving the problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As your code I had seen, I found one thing.

Rather than write `select * from aitimata` you just write this way`select <field1>,<fiedl2> from aitimata`.

I having practice of doing this way. Its working.

Check & Try my suggestion.
Thank You.
Manoj Kalla

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesnt work.... Is this relevant to the update procedure?

Comment: Nope...Unfortunately there no clue of what i'm doing wrong here...this article described the same procedure using a DataTable instead of a dataGridView